# Solving Knapsack using recursive algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, knapsack-problem

So, I am trying to implement this algorithm from our textbook.

[image]

I wrote this :

```
// Knapsack_memoryfunc.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//Solving Knapsack problem using dynamic programmig and Memory function

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "iomanip"
using namespace std;

int table[20][20] = { 0 };
int value, n, wt[20], val[20], max_wt;

// ---CONCERNED FUNCTION-----

int MNSack(int i, int j)
{
    value = 0;
    if (table[i][j] < 0)
        if (j < wt[i])
            value = MNSack(i - 1, j);
        else
            value = fmax(MNSack(i - 1, j), val[i] + MNSack(i - 1, j - wt[i]));

    table[i][j] = value;
    return table[i][j];
}

// --------------------------

void items_picked(int n, int max_wt)
{
    cout << "\n Items picked : " << endl;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        if (table[n][max_wt] == table[n - 1][max_wt])   // if value doesnot change in table column-wise, item isn't selected
            n--;                                        // n-- goes to next item
        else                                            // if it changes, it is selected
        {
            cout << " Item " << n << endl;
            max_wt -= wt[n];                            // removing weight from total available (max_wt)
            n--;                                        // next item
        }
    }
}

int main()
{

    cout << " Enter the number of items : ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << " Enter the Maximum weight : ";
    cin >> max_wt;
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cout << " Enter weight and value of item " << i << " : ";
        cin >> wt[i] >> val[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j <= max_wt; j++)
            table[i][j] = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= max_wt; j++)
            table[i][j] = -1;

    cout << " Optimum value : " << MNSack(n, max_wt);

    cout << " \n Table : \n";
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= max_wt; j++)
            if (table[i][j] == -1)
                cout << setw(5) << "-";
            else
                cout << setw(5) << table[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }

    items_picked(n, max_wt);


    return 0;
}
```

Here is the question and output :
[image]

It seems like its correct on some places like optimum value, yet isn't fully acceptable.
I've tried to debug it, but its quite hard with recursive functions. Can someone please help?

Comment: Heyho, i think HenryLee's answer is correct, but it still want to give you something for later. Ur code is a little bit terrible, and the way u solve this problem is called memoization under programmers. This is a beautiful blogpost, which helped me a lot and could make your code way more beautiful. http://programminggenin.blogspot.de/2013/01/memoization-in-c.html

Comment: @Mehno Can you elaborate? The algorithm, as I understand it, calculates only the required values.   How better can i implement it?

Comment: What @Mehno suggested was a technique that makes your coding style nicer. There is nothing bad in your algorithm. However, if you are interested, I can show you how to use a bottom-up dynamic programming to solve the same problem, which takes very few number of lines, and make the code much nicer.

Comment: @HenryLee Correct. The Algorithm is great. I just think, that using global variables for the matrix is a little bit ugly. There is nothing bad. I just thought it could be helpful to point to this technique.

Comment: @HenryLee If you've got a link or something for youre button up dynamic programming solution i would be glad. I might be able to learn something new ^^

Comment: Hi @Mehno , I posted it as another answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int MNSack(int i, int j)
{
    value = 0;
    if (table[i][j] < 0)
    {
        if (j < wt[i])
            value = MNSack(i - 1, j);
        else
            value = max(MNSack(i - 1, j), val[i] + MNSack(i - 1, j - wt[i]));

        table[i][j] = value;
    }
    return table[i][j];
}
```

The problem comes in here. When your table item is greater or equal to 0, you will skip the recursion but still set the table item to 0, which won't be right if your table item is greater than 0.

You only need to update the table item when it needs to be change, so put it in the braces will correct this.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom up solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int table[20][20] = { 0 };
    int value, n, wt[20], val[20], max_wt;

    cout << " Enter the number of items : ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << " Enter the Maximum weight : ";
    cin >> max_wt;
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cout << " Enter weight and value of item " << i << " : ";
        cin >> wt[i] >> val[i];
    }

    // Initialization
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j <= max_wt; j++)
            table[i][j] = 0;

    // In practice, this can be skipped in a bottom up solution
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= max_wt; j++)
            table[i][j] = -1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= max_wt; j++)
        {
            if (j < wt[i])
                table[i][j] = table[i - 1][j];
            else
                table[i][j] = max(table[i - 1][j], val[i] + table[i - 1][j - wt[i]]);
        }
    }

    cout << " Optimum value : " << table[n][max_wt] << endl;

    cout << " \n Table : \n";
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= max_wt; j++)
            if (table[i][j] == -1)
                cout << setw(5) << "-";
            else
                cout << setw(5) << table[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can see that this changes the recursion to a loop, and therefore avoids the global variables. It also makes the code simpler, so that you can avoid checking if the table item is valid (equal to -1 in your example).

The drawback of this solution is, it always traverses all the possible nodes. But it gains better coefficient per item because the recursion and double checking the table item costs more. Both top-down and bottom-up have the same order of complexity O(n^2), and it's hard to tell which one is faster.

Comment: Hey! I actually used this exact method to solve the problem before exploring the recursive method. Would it be possible to do this using recursion and not use global variables?

Comment: @LonelyC Good to hear that. It's always possible to do it without global variables, simply pass the variables as parameters in each function. Note that if you need to change the value of a parameter, you have to pass a reference (or pointer in C) of the variable instead. In this example, we only need to change values in the table, and since the table is passed as a pointer, we don't have to worry about that.